# Vertical centering with unknown height WITHOUT jQuery or display: table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

i'm working on a project with full-screen sections. Certain elements within the sections with the class "center-this" should be centered vertically. At first i was using jQuery to get the height of each element and center after, but some sections are hidden at first with display: none so they wont calculate the height correctly. There is no way of using jQuery becuase there is just too much hidden stuff and loading with ajax and automatic-onepage scrolling - it has to be with css.

Is there any way of centering in the middle without giving sections the display: table or display: inline ( this has to stay block - also the container in it has to stay display: block because it is in bootstrap) ?

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS code so that we can help you with what you have so far.

Comment: If you use [`fullpage.js`](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) you have a `verticalCentered` option.